# How to use Next-auth credentials provider with eternal API

Tags: node.js, jwt, next.js, next-auth

I worked with Next-auth before but I also used the built in next API feature. When used with next API, I can protect my APIs. The problem is now I am using an external node.js API. The token is created in the front end and this leaves my node API endpoints exposed. Is there something I'm missing here? How should I do this? Or tell me if there is a better way. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

You should not generate any **JWT** tokens in the frontend as that is way to insecure. Better to work if a dedicated and separate authorization service that generates the token for you. Either you host one your self or use a third party solution like [Auth0](https://auth0.com/) to generate the tokens for you.

Today more and more moves towards using the [BFF pattern](https://blog.bitsrc.io/bff-pattern-backend-for-frontend-an-introduction-e4fa965128bf) to further secure their SPA applications.